# How do I eliminate the spurious warning "value assigned is never read" in a macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I am new to Rust and am learning to write my own macros. This macro should fill my struct `MatrixXf` like the macro `vec!` does for `Vec<T>`.

```
//fills matrix with matlab like syntax
macro_rules! mat {
    [ $($( $x: expr ),*);* ] => {{
        let mut tmp_vec = Vec::new();
        let mut rows = 0;
        let mut cols = 0;
        let mut is_first_row_collected = false;
        $(
            let mut inner_cols = 0;
            $(
                tmp_vec.push($x);
                inner_cols += 1;
            )*
            if is_first_row_collected {//if we read first row we can check that other rows have same length
                assert!(inner_cols == cols);
            } else {
                is_first_row_collected = true;
                cols = inner_cols;
            }
            rows += 1;
        )*
        MatrixXf::construct(tmp_vec, rows, cols)//fills MatrixXf fields
    }}
}
```

And I use it this way:

```
let mat = mat![1.0, 2.0, 3.0; 4.0, 5.0, 6.0];
```

Everything is ok, but the compiler shows me the following warning:

> 7:23 warning: value assigned to `is_first_row_collected` is never read, #[warn(unused_assignments)] on by default
>   :7 is_first_row_collected = true ; cols = inner_cols ; } rows += 1 ; ) *

Maybe I misunderstood something, but I do use `is_first_row_collected` when checking that the first row was visited. Is it possible to rewrite my code to avoid this warning?

Comment: Don't worry about your English! I absolutely understood what you're asking. I fixed up one or two small things in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is real; let's use this modified example that doesn't rely on a structure that you didn't provide in your question:

```
macro_rules! mat {
    [ $($( $x: expr ),*);* ] => {{
        let mut tmp_vec = Vec::new();
        let mut rows = 0;
        let mut cols = 0;
        let mut is_first_row_collected = false;
        $(
            let mut inner_cols = 0;
            $(
                tmp_vec.push($x);
                inner_cols += 1;
            )*
            if is_first_row_collected {//if we read first row we can check that other rows have same length
                assert!(inner_cols == cols);
            } else {
                is_first_row_collected = true;
                cols = inner_cols;
            }
            rows += 1;
        )*
        (tmp_vec, rows, cols)
    }}
}

fn main() {
    let _mat = mat![1.0, 2.0, 3.0; 4.0, 5.0, 6.0];
}
```

We can then use the compiler to see what the expanded version is:

```
rustc -Z unstable-options --pretty expanded example.rs
```

This is a big, ugly blob of code, so I'll trim it down to the relevant parts:

```
fn main() {
    let mut is_first_row_collected = false;

    if is_first_row_collected {
        // removed
    } else {
        is_first_row_collected = true;
    }

    if is_first_row_collected {
        // removed
    } else {
        is_first_row_collected = true;
    }
}
```

So, indeed, the *value you assigned is never read*. Of course, as a human you can see that that particular flow shouldn't happen, and perhaps you could request an enhancement to the compiler to track that.

Ideally, you'd rework your macro to not have the underlying problem. [Francis Gagné shows a great way of doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32877780/155423). If you can't rework the macro, you can allow that warning. Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to add the `#[allow(unused_assignments)]` declaration on anything but a `fn` or a `mod`, so it seems like you'd have to do some changes to your macro anyway.

Comment: "structure that you didn't provide in your question" i thought that kind of structure is not matter in this question. I'll provide structure description in my further questions. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @Dark_Daiver you are right that it doesn't matter in this case, but the *best* questions are the ones that can be pasted into [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) and show the error you are getting. This is called an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Then people don't have to modify your example code to be runnable, potentially changing it and getting a different error (and cause of that error), making a useless answer and wasting time.

Comment: I agree with you. Small as possible examples which describes question is important.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a boolean variable, you could wrap `cols` in an `Option` to make it clear that `cols` has no valid value until you read the first row.

```
//fills matrix with matlab like syntax
macro_rules! mat {
    [ $($( $x: expr ),*);* ] => {{
        let mut tmp_vec = Vec::new();
        let mut rows = 0;
        let mut cols = None;
        $(
            let mut inner_cols = 0;
            $(
                tmp_vec.push($x);
                inner_cols += 1;
            )*
            if let Some(cols) = cols {//if we read first row we can check that other rows have same length
                assert!(inner_cols == cols);
            } else {
                cols = Some(inner_cols);
            }
            rows += 1;
        )*
        MatrixXf::construct(tmp_vec, rows, cols.unwrap_or(0))//fills MatrixXf fields
    }}
}
```

Another option is to handle the first row and the following rows differently by separating them in the macro's pattern. This way, we can avoid the flag entirely because when we handle the following rows, we already know the number of columns.

```
//fills matrix with matlab like syntax
macro_rules! mat {
    [] => { MatrixXf::construct(Vec::new(), 0, 0) };
    [ $( $x: expr ),* $(; $( $y: expr ),*)* ] => {{
        let mut tmp_vec = Vec::new();
        let mut rows = 0;
        let mut inner_cols = 0;
        $(
            tmp_vec.push($x);
            inner_cols += 1;
        )*
        let cols = inner_cols; // remember how many columns the first row has
        rows += 1;
        $(
            inner_cols = 0;
            $(
                tmp_vec.push($y);
                inner_cols += 1;
            )*
            assert!(inner_cols == cols); // check that the following rows have as many columns as the first row
            rows += 1;
        )*
        MatrixXf::construct(tmp_vec, rows, cols)//fills MatrixXf fields
    }}
}
```

In this version of the macro, I added another rule to construct an empty matrix when there are no arguments and I moved the location of the semicolon so that you don't need a trailing semicolon when you have only one row.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your post exactly answers my question but post from Shepmaster shows me that i was mistaken about spurious warning. So i cannot decide which post i should mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would look like something in the lint is off here. If you manually expand the code yourself, do you still get the warning? Or is it just when it's in a macro?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I wrote something similiar to my macro but with for loops instead $()* (i dont know how implement it outside macros). And there is no warning.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me then.

Comment: bug in rustc? (My version is 1.2.0)

Comment: Yup! I don't remember seeing one come through the tracker, but if you can get a test case, I think you should file it. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/new (and 1.3 has come out, too, btw)

Comment: Oh new version, nice) Rustc still show me warning so i will try to send bug report